# Difference between aggregation and operator

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have been reading up on some mongodb documentation and ran across some confusing terminology, namely how to differentiate when a symbol will be used as an aggregate function or as an operator.

For example, the `$size` function either calculates the number of items in an array, or checks if the number of elements in an array is equal to a number, is there any way to know what the function will do at what time? Through trial and error I discovered that the $size will throw an error unless a number is passed to it in the $match step, but is there some rule/guideline so I can know what it will do beforehand?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      key: 1,
      number: {
        $size: "$key"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      key: {
        $size: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 4):

For querying data in MongoDB you can use the [find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html) method or the [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method. There are ***operators*** which you can use with these methods.

These [query operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/) are used with the `find` method. Some of these can also used with the `$match` stage of the `aggregate` method (details later in the post).

These [aggregation pipeline operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) are used within the `aggregate`'s stages. Some of these can also be used with the `find` method (details later in the post).

You will notice that, there are common ***operator names***; for example, `$eq`, `$gte`, `$or`, `$type`, `$size`, etc. But, their usage and / or functionality can be different. The `$eq` operator has same function but different usage syntax and the `$type`operator has different functionality (and usage syntax).

And, some of these operators can be used with both the methods.

---

**Some Usage Scenarios:**

Lets consider a `users` collection and some queries:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "age" : 21, "firstname" : "John" }
{ "_id" : 2, "age" : 18, "firstname" : "John" }
{ "_id" : 3, "age" : "39", "firstname" : "Johnson" }
```

The query:

```
db.users.find( { firstname: { $eq: "John"}, age: { $gt: 20 } } )
```

This query's filter is same as `{ firstname: "John"}, age: { $gt: 20 } }`. This uses the query operators [$eq](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/) and [$gt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/).  The same query can be written in the `aggregate` method's `$match` stage:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { $match: { firstname: "John", age: { $gt: 20 } } },
])
```

The operators used in this case are the same *query operators*. The query *comparison* operators can be used with the `aggregate` method's `$match` and `$lookup` stages.

---

**Another Scenario:**

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { $project: { ageGreaterThan20: { $gt: [ "$age", 20 ] } } },
])
```

This is the usage of aggregation *comparison* operator [$gt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/). Note this is used within the aggregation query, but within the `$project` stage.

As you had used the *query operators* in the aggregation query, you can also use the *aggregation operators* within the `find` method. But, this must be used with the "special" [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) operator. For example:

```
db.users.find( { $expr: { $gt: [ "$age", 20 ] } } )
```

The advantage of the `$expr` is that - there are number of *aggregation operators* which can be used within the `find` queries. For example, using the `$strLenCP`:

```
db.users.find( { $expr: { $gt: [ { $strLenCP: "$firstname" }, 4 ] } } )
```

You can also use the `$expr` within the aggregation, within the `$match` or `$lookup` stages:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { $match: { $expr: { $gt: [ "$age", 20 ] } } },
])
```

---

**Finally:**

> I have been reading up on some mongodb documentation and ran across
>   some confusing terminology, namely how to differentiate when a symbol
>   will be used as an aggregate function or as an operator. ... but is
>   there some rule/guideline so I can know what it will do beforehand?

Reading helps, practicing helps better and experience helps the best. You use a specific operator in a specific scenario or use case. To achieve some functionality you use an appropriate method and operator(s).

***Reference:*** [Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/)

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, I'm pointing out few things :

> Difference between aggregation and operator

You'll have certain basic functions for [crud operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/crud/) like `.find() or .insert() or .delete() or .update()` on MongoDB (There are few others like `.count()`, `.distinct()` but those are primary)

***Versus***

[aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) is a whole framework heavily used for complex **reads**, only two stages in aggregation is capable of **writes** `$out` and `$merge`.

**Operators :**

There are different types of [operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/) :

[Query and Projection Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/) : These operators are crucial and are used to filter docs and to transform fields of docs in the response, Usually used in ***filter*** and ***project*** part of `.find(filter, project) or .update(filter, update, project/options)` etc.. These are also used in `$match` stage of aggregation pipeline (`$match` is similar to filter in `.find()`). **Ex.** :- `$and`, `$or`, `$in`, `$or` & more.

[Update Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/) : By name, these operators help to update documents in the collection. Usually used in ***update*** part of `.update() or .findOneAndUpdate()` etc.. **Ex.** :- `$set`, `$unset`, `$inc` & more.

**Aggregation :**

When it comes to aggregation they call it **aggregation framework**, definitely for a reason as you can do a lot of things with data using aggregation.

Aggregation has ***aggregation pipeline*** , which has syntax `.aggregate([])`. pipeline is an array with [stages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline-stages). Each stage in aggregation does certain operation on data flowing through them. Ex. :- `$match`, `$project`, `$group` etc..

As we know each document is *independent* on it's own, most of aggregation stages operate independently on each doc flowing through them.

[Aggregation pipeline Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) :

These operators are generally used to achieve what you're looking for, certain operators can't be used in conjunction with other operators or in a stage. 
Let's say in `$match` stage you would mostly use ***Query operators*** but not ***Aggregation operators*** as aggregation operators can't directly be used in `$match` in contrast with `$project` or `$addFields` stages.

**Example with Stages & Operators :**

Let's say you got to make Smoothie :

1. Out of a bunch of groceries you would filter needed fruits(docs in fruits collection) by matching with what you wanted to blend using `$match` stage (`$and` to match fruits/veggies, `$lt` to filter only fruits that hasn't expired and `$size` to limit no.of fruits needed).
2. You would peel off skin or chop into pieces to keep just keep useful parts of fruits(docs) using `$project`.
3. You would group all of the fruits into a blender using `$group` & add ingredients like cream & sugar using `$addFields` - You're too cautious about sugar quantity so you'll use **operators** like `$size` to check size and `$multiply` no.of nutrients based on conditions (`$cond`) you would `$divide` both `sugar/nutrients` to count nutrition value.
4. You'll iterate on adding ice pieces again and again using `$map`, `$filter` to remove un crushed ice pieces.
5. uhh, you always forget to add veggies (A different collection needs to be merged) based on fruits that already got blended you use `$lookup` to lookup for matching veggies(docs) & either blend in again with group or just put it on top.
6. Finally either you drink it from blender (just return the docs no more stages) or take into glass using `$out` or `$merge` stage (Remember as I said, only two stages that can write to a collection).

Off course every stage is Optional - You can eat fruits as is instead of blending (get all docs and all their fields) but you know what you wouldn't do that (for many reasons like performance, unnecessary data flowing through network) unless it's pre-prepared product (like a small configuration collection which has limited data with few docs & every doc is need & can be easily retrieved in one DB call).

**Note :**

Usually you can't use aggregation operators in ***filter*** part i.e; `.find(filter) or in '$match' stage` unless you use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html).

Starting MongoDB v`4.2` you can run aggregation pipeline in [update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline) where you can take advantage of aggregation stages/operators in ***update*** part.

While you search MongoDB's documentation often you would find the same operator in multiple places, Let's say if you search for `$size` you would find multiple references one is Query operator or as Projection operator or as aggregation operator - So depends on need/where you wanted to use you can refer their documentation for usage cause though name seems to be similar or does almost same but functionality may differ & syntax also differs.

You can always MongoDB for free at [MongoDB University](https://university.mongodb.com).