# mongo aggregation difference in match stage using $expr vs not using $expr

Tags: mongodb

I am a bit confused as to when exactly I do need to use $expr inside a $match stage.

For example, when I want to match against a documents property of lets say "fruit" and I do

$match: {fruit: 'banana'} it returns the correct values with only fruits of bananas.

I often times read about using $match in combination with $expr and $eq which results in the same data output.

When exactly do I have to use  $expr then if it works without it as well?

Comment: You will find some related info in this post [Difference between aggregation and operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61944092/difference-between-aggregation-and-operator/61947691#61947691)

Comment: Hm still after reading dont get the difference. They showed the usage of it but not exactly what is the difference in using them when both work.  I wouldnt have asked on here if I didnt read the mongo docs already as well.

Comment: You can use the, for example, `$eq` operator with `$expr` or without it in the `$match` stage. There are two _different_ `$eq` operators, and one of them can be used in each case. And, they have different purposes. You need to know the difference between these two `$eq` operators and their usage. Lookup the documentation and try more examples.